# Who authored the Yehi Ratzon said after Tehilim?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, authorship

When one says Tehilim there is a [Yehi Ratzon](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40084&st=&pgnum=699) which is published at the end which says "to be said after saying Tehilim". Who authored this Yehi Ratzon?

Comment: related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22224/when-does-one-recite-the-verses-preceding-and-following-the-recitation-of-tehill

Comment: Probably someone Sephardi.

Answer (score 3):

Israel Davidson's compendium refers the reader to 'שער השמים', namely the סידור השל"ה. Since קיצור של"ה also features this prayer, my educated guess is that its authorship may be attributed to 'של"ה literature', if not the של"ה himself.